# How to solve strong parameters' contradiction when editing an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The problem I'm facing most likely has something to do with strong parameters. The thing is when I try to edit some user information and update it, an error appears which is not related with this form. That kind of error's supposed to pop up only when signing up or logging in.

For example, here is my database. And then I click 'Edit'.

[image]

After editing some information and submitting it, the error pops up.

[image]

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to [@user, @task], notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    respond_to {|format| format.js }
  end

  private


  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

**views/user/edit.html**

```
<h1>Editing user</h1>

<%= form_for :user, url: @user, method: :patch do |f| %>

  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this task from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <%= link_to 'Back to List', users_path %>

<% end %>
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

   EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :first_name, presence: true,
            length: {maximum: 20}
  validates :last_name,  presence: true,
            length: {maximum: 40}
  validates :email, presence: true,
            format: {with: EMAIL_REGEX},
            uniqueness:  {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password,
            length: {within: 6..40}

  has_many :tasks
end
```

What do I do? Can anybody help?

Comment: Try changing this  `validates :password,length: {within: 6..40}` to `validates :password,length: {within: 6..40}, on: :create`

Comment: @Pavan Create an answer so I can accept this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is ***not*** with the `strong params`. It is due to ***validation*** you have on `password`.

This

```
validates :password,length: {within: 6..40}
```

should be

```
validates :password,length: {within: 6..40}, on: :create
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is in strong params. You should never permit `password` and `password_confirmation`

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
end
```

Just remove `password` and `password_confirmation` from `user_params`. You wouldn't want to mass assign those values.

And this would be a very bad practice to store a plain password in database. You should store encrypted or hashed password in database; it would enhance the security and integrity of your application.

To get more information about storing an encrypted or hashed password, please take a look at [this](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/8/3/users-and-passwords/) and [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/) links.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. But I get to know what's wrong with it.

Comment: You are doing it wrong from the beginning. There should be no `password` field in database. Rather it should be `hashed_password` or `encrypted_password`.